# Why are we interested in proper holomorphic embeddings?

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry

Dealing with an $n$-dimensional Stein manifold $X$, a problem which captured the attention was to find proper holomorphic embeddings
$$
f\colon X\hookrightarrow\Bbb C^N
$$
for some $N$. Of course the first problem has been to prove existence of such mappings, which has been proved by Remmert in 1956; in particuar he proved that such p.h.e. exists for $N$ sufficiently large; afterwards the focus moved towards minimizing $N$; and roughly speaking I can see why: the smaller $N$, the tighter the space into which we are *concretely* realizing our abstract object $X$ (namely, as $f(X)$), more faithful such a representation.

Moreover, it seems reasonable to work with mappings which are

- holomorphic, as we are dealing with complex manifolds, this somehow preserves the complex structure of $X$;
- proper, so that it behaves well with respect to boundaries;
- embedding, so that the image is one-to-one and the differential of maximum rank is the best condition against singularities.

So, I have a Stein manifold, I want to search for some equivalent object, which is more "concrete" (so we look for some euclidean space). But WHY proper holomorphic embeddings and not other kind of mappings? Moreover, does exist some reference in which what I above broadly described, is therein properly explained?

Comment: My understanding is that it is easy to see that if a manifold admits a proper holomorphic embedding, then it is Stein, and it is interesting to see if it is an iff (i.e. "Stein manifolds are affine")

Comment: I would like to understand the downvote. I cannot see where am I wrong with my question